# How to solve exponential equation $a + bx + c\exp(x) + dx\exp(x) = 0$?

Tags: exponential-function

I'm trying to solve:

$a + bx + c\exp(x) + dx\exp(x) = 0$

I didn't get any further than rewriting it as:

$(x+c/d)(\exp(x)+b/d) = bc - a/d$

Which doesn't get me anywhere. If someone is able to help me with this that would be great!

Comment: I'm pretty sure this has no closed-form solution.  And it may have anywhere from zero to one to two solutions, depending on the values of the constants.  Can you expand more on the context here?

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. The reason I write it in this general form is that the values of a, b, c and d are complex (a function of several parameters) and irrelevant. I need to solve this equation as part of a research project.

Answer (score 0):

$$a + bx + c\exp(x) + dx\exp(x) = 0 \implies e^{-x}=-\frac{c+dx } {a+bx }$$ So, the equation can be solved in terms of the [generalized Lambert function](https://arxiv.org/abs/1408.3999) (have a look at equation $(4)$).

This being said, think about a numerical method such as Newton.